# How to add dynamical input fields for the form submit in Vue3/Nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am working with Nuxt3 form and need to add or remove an input field when I click add/remove button.

For example, I have 3 input fields: "Place1, Place2, Place3" and a button for submit the form.

If I click the "ADD" button, I want to add a new field "Place4", "Place5" and so on.
Also, I might need to remove any input field when I click remove button.

Is there any way to adjust the input fields dynamically?

Thanks.

I used v-for statement for this, and it has the same value when I add the input field.
But each input field should have a different value each other.

Comment: Your question makes almost no sense. This is because your text is probably translated and is in unclear English. Secondly, you supplied no code whatsoever.. Remember that code is universal and is easier to understand then this description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with this codes.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

const places = ref(['', '', ''])

const addField = () => {
    places.value.push('')
}

const formRef = ref<HTMLFormElement | null>(null)

const removePlace = (index: number) => {
    places.value.splice(index, 1)
}

const submitForm = () => {
    if (formRef.value) {
        const formData = new FormData(formRef.value)
        for (const [fieldName, fieldValue] of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(`${fieldName} :`, fieldValue)
        }
        formRef.value.reset()
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <form
            @submit.prevent="submitForm"
            ref="formRef"
        >
            <div
                v-for="(place, index) in places"
                :key="index"
                style="margin-bottom: 10px;"
            >
                <label>Place {{ index + 1 }}</label>
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        :placeholder="`Place${index + 1}`"
                        :name="`place${index + 1}`"
                    />
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        @click="removePlace(index)"
                    >Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; gap: 10px;">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    @click="addField"
                >
                    Add Field
                </button>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<style></style>
```

Tested and it works!